# Problems with proxy server in react app with node.js express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have simple express server in server.js

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express(); 
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000; 


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)); 


app.get('/express_backend', (req, res) => { 
  res.send({ "express":"have data"}); 
});
```

also component

```
import { Component } from "react";
import './../css/Rings.css'
import SellItem from "./sellItem";
import Fotter from "./fotter";

    class Necklase extends Component{
        state ={
            data: null
        };
        componentDidMount() {
            this.callBackendAPI()
              .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.express }))
              .catch(err => console.log(err));
          }
        callBackendAPI = async () => {
            const response = await fetch('/express_backend');
            const body = await response.json();
            console.log(body.express)
            if (response.status !== 200) {
              throw Error(body.message) 
            }
            return body;
          };
        render(){
    
    
    
            return   <div >
            <div className="main">
                <SellItem/>
    
            </div>
            {this.state.data}
            <Fotter/>
        </div>
        }
    }
    export default Necklase
```

when i start my react app with npm start in package json npm start looks like this now, also it is proxy

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

and after it i start server.js with node server.js in cmd everything work fine, i can get data from response and display it but if i change "start" to this

```
"start": "react-scripts start && nodemon server.js  ",
```

i got this error in console

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /express_backend from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

and this when i console.log(body.express) in callBackendAPI

SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this way

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./app.js",
```